# Symfony Doctrine n:m relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my application I'm having a n:m relationship in my database,
"A user has many objects and an object has many User"

so the database looks like:
user->user_obj<-obj

when I want to save an object to the database, the object gets stores, but the relation (user_id and obj_id) in the n:m table (user_obj) not

Is there any simple way to save the Obj ID and the User ID into the database

```
    if ($form->isValid()) {            
        //persist
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($obj);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mypathname'));
    }
```

Comment: php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --with-write for your current entity ? It generates all actions : edit, create, update, delete, show and index

Comment: thanks a los ! this is what a exactly needed ! now i can call bevore persisting $obj->addXyz($this->getUser()); Thanks so much !